# SwiftUI. TabView animation with ScrollView on a tab

Tags: animation, swiftui, scrollview, watchos, tabview

I am trying to create tabs in TabView with program animated transition between them on watchOS. But if I add ScrollView in the tab, then the animation is disappearing. How can it be fixed?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
            Text("Tab 0").tag(0)
            
            VStack {
                Button("To 0") {
                    withAnimation { currentTab = 0 }
                }
                ScrollView { // if ScrollView is deleted, all work properly
                    Text("Some information.")
                }
            }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible, provide, a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue on watchOS 9.1